# x86 emulator in JavaScript to run Linux, Windows or DOS

Tags: open-source, javascript, emulator

I'm looking for an open-source PC/x86 emulator which I can run in a web browser using JavaScript so I can run Linux, Windows or DOS.

Preferably with network support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are few emulators which I've found so far:

- [v86](http://copy.sh/v86/): PC emulator ([GitHub](https://github.com/copy/v86)).

  Can run Linux, Windows 1.01, FreeDOS, BSD or custom HDD/Floppy disk images.
- [jor1k](http://s-macke.github.io/jor1k/demos/main.html): OpenRISC OR1K CPU emulator ([GitHub](https://github.com/s-macke/jor1k/)).

  With network support (including [SSL](https://github.com/s-macke/jor1k/issues/65)).
- [angel](http://riscv.org/angel/): RISC-V CPU emulator ([GitHub](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-angel)).
- [JSLinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) (Javascript PC Emulator) by Javascript PC Emulator for non-commercial use only (check [FAQ](http://bellard.org/jslinux/faq.html), for unofficial sources check this [GitHub](https://github.com/levskaya/jslinux-deobfuscated)),

  > There is no network emulation at this point.

Comment: That is an impressive starting point... thanks for sharing your research. Hopefully others will be able to help.